# How to remove the div that a button is contained in when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to remove a div when the button inside of it is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
            <button class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
            <button class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function registerClickHandler() {
  // Register click event handler for button of class 'remove'
    "use strict";
    var node = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    if (node.parentNode) {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
}

var listen = document.getElementbyClassName("remove");
listen.addEventListener("click", registerClickHandler());
```

So when I click the 'X' button inside of the div, I need it to remove the entire parent div, but it seems like nothing I've tried will work. I'm not sure if maybe I'm not using event handlers the right way or not, or if something I'm doing is just completely wrong. I would like to do this without using jQuery (because I don't really know it) if possible, but a lot of the solutions I've seen for vaguely similar problems have all used jQuery.

**Edit:**
I forgot to specify that I am looking for a way to accomplish this using `eventHandlers`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) you can change element selector by pref

*"The **Element.closest()** method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself) which matches the selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns null."*

> mind that with a **"proper selector"** you don't have to worry about the parent or grandparent on elements selection

Here is an example.

```
function setup() {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.target.closest('div.image').remove();
        });
    }
}
setup();
```

```css
img {
  width:100px;  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    function setup() {
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.target.closest('div.image').remove();
                //e.target.closest('.image').remove();
                
                //this will not work on 2 last images cause parent div will be deleted 
                //leaving an empty <div class="image"></div> for each removed item
                
                //e.target.closest('div').remove();
            });
        }
    }
    setup();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function removeDiv(btn){
            ((btn.parentNode).parentNode).removeChild(btn.parentNode);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
        <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
        <button class="remove" onclick="removeDiv(this);">X</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does work, thank you! I was specifically looking for a way to use eventHandlers though as a form of practice because I'm not the best at them.

Comment: You're welcome. if you want to learn more about Javascript I think [this from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction) and [this](http://javascript.info/) will be useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementbyClassName` is the wrong syntax. You're looking for `getElementsByClassName`. This returns an array like object (HTMLCollection), not a node, and you will need to apply the event listener to each element individually. You also don't need to use `removeChild`. That's a bit redundant.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.parentNode.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```js
element = $(".remove");

for (var i in element) {
  element.on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach:

`<button type="button" onclick="return this.parentNode.remove();">Remove</button>`

Also works if the parent element and its children were dynamically created.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is having issues.
The working code is

```js
function registerClickHandler() {
  // Register click event handler for button of class 'remove'
   "use strict";
   this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
var listen = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < listen.length; i++) {
 listen[i].addEventListener("click", registerClickHandler);
}
```

```html
  <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
            <button class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
            <button class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
```

Now, Issues

1. wrong function call at    **var listen = document.getElementbyClassName("remove");**
2. Function returns an array. you have to loop over it.
3. To refer to clicked element in function need to use **this**
4. Last to remove parent element you need to refer parent of parent. Then remove **this.parent**.

.

Comment: Ah, dumb mistake on the syntax. For some reason, when I run your code from this window it works perfectly but when I copy to my local file it stops working. I was running it in chrome both times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
            <button class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
            <button class="remove">X</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function removeParent() {
                this.parentNode.remove();
            }
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(d, i) {
                d.addEventListener('click', removeParent);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I tried this code, it didn't work for me, button click did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to remove the parent element

```js
function removeParent(parent) {
 parent.remove();
}
```

```html
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VuKnN5P.jpg" alt="First">
            <button class="remove" onclick ="removeParent(this.parentNode)">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ee4QOKe.jpg" alt="Second">
            <button class="remove" onclick ="removeParent(this.parentNode)">X</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the button tag does not have onclick function. For this, you need to self invoke function. Here is my answer.

```
(function registerClickHandler() {
   var classLength = document.getElementsByClassName("remove").length;
   for(var i = 0; i<classLength; i++){ 
   document.getElementsByClassName("remove")
   [i].addEventListener("click",function(current){
       current.srcElement.parentElement.remove();
   });
  }
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
const registerClickHandler = ()  => {
x = document.getElementsByClassName("remove") 
for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){ 
           x[i].addEventListener("click",function(current){
               current.srcElement.parentElement.remove();
           });
          }
        }
```